# getting unexpected error from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am doing an ajax request from chrome extension to an API to get data.

however, there were first CORS erros but I fixed it and now, some ambigious errors are coming and showing the links merged. However, the requested API link always returns a STATUS of 200 which is okay but there is some issue from the current page on which I am executing CONTENT SCRIPTS in chrome extension as:

```
"content_scripts": [
 {
    "matches": ["https://example.com/auth*"],
    "js": ["lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "scripts/main.js"]
  }
]
```

and my AJAX request is:

```
$.ajax({
        url: get_companies_url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error){
          console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

However, this Ajax request is getting data but always going to ERROR block as can be in the image below:
[image: Error Image]

In the above image, the last line (onreadyStateChange: 4) is consoled by the ERROR block but the Uncaught Error: Unexpected tocken : (red colored error), is the response as:

```
{
"user": "aaaa",
"name": "sadasd",
"comapnies" : { 
"company_id": 12871,
......etc
}
....etc etc
}
```

Actually, that error is coming the FULL COLON ":" after the "user" key in JSON above.

[image: JSON FUll colon error]
Please, Help. Thanks

Also,
I am getting this error: **"XMLHttpRequest cannot load webapi.timasdasdor.com/v11.1/…. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://bknfamagldkbcppmcpjlmjabekjlknii' is therefore not allowed access."** WHEN i am using this AJAX GET REQUEST as:

```
$.get(get_companies_url, function(data, status){ console.log(data); });
```

Comment: Can you please show me proper response you got?

Comment: Actually, I want to get data from an App using API request while using an access_token and I am getting the response but things are garbled and can be seen in the first pic, I then uploaded in question. However, this is the result of the API GET CALL and can be accessed directly in bowser when correct access_token is given. {"user":{"full_name":"Owais","email":"owaisk@gmail.com","url":"https:\/\exacple.timdsadasd.com\/v1.1\/companies"},"accounts":[{"user_id":1022023,"company_id":548673,"type":"owner","company_name":"Muhammad's Company","url":"https:1.1\/companies\/548673\/"}]}

Comment: first error, 404, is a page not found error. Second error, the syntax error, is because you are returning json when jsonp is expecting javascript. "Note that for JSONP to work, a server must reply with a response that includes the JSONP function. JSONP does not work with JSON-formatted results." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: I am doing AJAX request from URL : https://example.com/auth to API request at URL: https://getcompanies/user

Comment: I am getting this error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://webapi.timasdasdor.com/v11.1/companies?access_token=NzllMWVkODQxNmM0OGZjYjU1YzFhZWE5NjM5ZTlkOTE4NDRjZTM5MWM5NzcyOWE3MDQ1MzNkMjBhYTcyZDEwMw. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://bknfamagldkbcppmcpjlmjabekjlknii' is therefore not allowed access." WHEN i am using this AJAX GET REQUEST as: $.get(get_companies_url, function(data, status){
      console.log(data);
    });

Comment: Please add code and errors as **text** ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy & paste the code/errors for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error contents; and C) [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). In general, code/errors in text format >>> code/errors as an image >>> nothing.  Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error.

Answer (score 0):

As, I was developing chrome extension, I used below code

```
"permissions" : [
    "*://example.domain.com/v1/*"
  ],
```

and the error **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** was fixed.

Hope, this helps others.

Thanks